# How to remove or hide the Header Parameter in Swagger-UI version 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springfox

I am working on the Swagger-UI version is 3.0.0. when I implemented the swagger annotation my APIs were showing some extra parameters in swagger-UI. Parameter looks like

"acceptableLanguages[0].country" "acceptableLanguages[0].displayCountry"

I am using springfox dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is my docket code.

```
@Bean
    public Docket docket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("title")
            .description("Demo")
            .build();
}
```

This is the API header code to which I am I am referring. There is nothing like acceptableLanguages[0].country which I have added but still, it is showing in my Swagger UI. This acceptableLanguages[0].country is showing even before adding @ApiImplicitParams

```
@ApiImplicitParams({
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "ID", value = "ID", paramType = "header"),})
```

I am also adding a screenshot of the UI. Any help will be great.
[Swagger UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fROC.png)
I want to remove acceptableLanguages[0].displayCountry and all other Paramters.

Comment: can you post the other dependencies that you have in your pom.xml file?

Comment: do you mean for swagger? I just add this dependency
`<dependency>`
`<groupId>io.swagger</groupId>`
`<artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>` 
`<version>1.6.2</version>`
`</dependency>`
`<dependency>`
`<groupId>io.springfox</groupId>`
`<artifactId>springfox-core</artifactId>`
`<version>3.0.0</version>`
`<scope>compile</scope>`
`</dependency>`

Comment: Do you have `acceptableLanguages` anywhere in the source code?

Comment: No I don't have that anywhere in my code.

Comment: Just wanted to add one thing. I checked the HTML code in the browser it is showing as data-para-in = "query".